# Is it possible to read/fetch added customised token in metamask in react?

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, web3js, metamask

I am trying to add ERC20 token to metamask from react js. First time it gets added. But whenever I refresh the page it asks to re-add the token. Is there a way to check the token is already added.

If its already added it should not promt user to add the token.
Is there a way to code this in react?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, at the moment, there is no API to check if MetaMask has any token added. You can only request users to add the token via [wallet_watchAsset](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/registering-your-token.html#example) API.